# Java Swing apps steal/don't release focus in KDE

Tags: linux, java, kde, kubuntu, swing

Kubuntu 14.04 (64bit) with KDE 4.13.3, Java Oracle 1.7.0_80-b15

This problem first occured in 12.04 and persists.
Java version does not affect the behaviour, i.e. the same happens with 1.6 to 1.8.

Reproduce:

1. Start 2-3 "regular" programs like Firefox/Chrome/Kate.
2. Start Java Swing application (Intellij Idea / jvisualvm / Visual paradigm / other)
3. Click on "Show the desktop"
4. Start "regular" program (firefox), it shows up fullscreen

**The problem: keyboard focus is still in the Swing app and if you try to type the input is send to it.**

This is extremly annoying if you use some IDE of the Intelij family because often the typing intended for some other app ends up in your source file.

I've already tried with different setting of the KDE's "Focus stealing prevention" (System settings -> Window Behaviour) but to no avail.

Java apps that are not using Swing (e.g. Eclipse) does not have this problem. Only Swing apps.

Does someone have a solution for this problem or at least:

- is able to confirm it
- direct me to the suitable bug tracker (swing? kde?) so I can report it

xprop of the swing app (Intellij idea):

```
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1e0003c
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 3581
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_NAME(STRING) = "plasma-desktop"
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Plasma", "Plasma"
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x1e00235
                window id # of group leader: 0x1e0003c
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: 0, 0
                program specified location: 0, 0
                user specified size: 1920 by 1080
                program specified size: 1920 by 1080
                window gravity: Static
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "OgrePC"
WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "/usr/bin/plasma-desktop" }
ogre@OgrePC:~/aprojects-src/as_projects/besenica/besenica_core$ xprop
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x45, 0x0, 0x40, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 107, 1011, 202, 34
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE
_KDE_NET_WM_FRAME_STRUT(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 20, 0
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 20, 0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES(STRING) = "5c2b1a8d-8274-46bf-abfa-a0db6a775d03"
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x3, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: False
                Initial state is Normal State.
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =        Icon (128 x 128):
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 9027
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "OgrePC"
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_TAKE_FOCUS, WM_DELETE_WINDOW
_KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 35443779
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "jetbrains-idea-ce"
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x3400005
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "gg_platform - [~/aprojects-src/as_projects/gg_platform] - gg_platform_kryo_server - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "gg_platform - [~/aprojects-src/as_projects/gg_platform] - gg_platform_kryo_server - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "gg_platform - [~/aprojects-src/as_projects/gg_platform] - gg_platform_kryo_server - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "gg_platform - [~/aprojects-src/as_projects/gg_platform] - gg_platform_kryo_server - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: -3, -3
                program specified location: -3, -3
                program specified size: 1916 by 984
                window gravity: NorthWest
```

xprop of the desktop:

```
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 43963890  
_KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES(STRING) = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):     
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) =   
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 31457847
_KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 133564
_NET_STARTUP_ID(UTF8_STRING) = "0"      
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 4294967295  
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =        Icon (16 x 16):



XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1e0003c
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 3581
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_NAME(STRING) = "plasma-desktop"
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Plasma", "Plasma"
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x1e00235
                window id # of group leader: 0x1e0003c
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: 0, 0
                program specified location: 0, 0
                user specified size: 1920 by 1080
                program specified size: 1920 by 1080
                window gravity: Static
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "OgrePC"
WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "/usr/bin/plasma-desktop" }
```

xprop of the program (firefox) started after "Show desktop"

```
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 1163, 1045, 176, 34
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACT
_KDE_NET_WM_FRAME_STRUT(CARDINAL) = 3, 3, 23, 4
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 3, 3, 23, 4
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES(STRING) = "5c2b1a8d-8274-46bf-abfa-a0db6a775d03"
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x3e6967d
                bitmap id # of mask for icon: 0x3e6967e
                window id # of group leader: 0x3e00001
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "browser"
_KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 44424608
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =        Icon (16 x 16):


_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 1163, 1045, 176, 34
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE
_KDE_NET_WM_FRAME_STRUT(CARDINAL) = 3, 3, 23, 4
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 3, 3, 23, 4
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES(STRING) = "5c2b1a8d-8274-46bf-abfa-a0db6a775d03"
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x3e59b19
                bitmap id # of mask for icon: 0x3e59b1a
                window id # of group leader: 0x3e00001
_NET_STARTUP_ID(UTF8_STRING) = "OgrePC;1430761118;209192;3581_TIME42982583"
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "browser"
_KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 42982594
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =        Icon (16 x 16):

              ░░░░      
            ░▒░░░░░     
          ░▒▒░▒░░░▒░    
          ▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒    
         ░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░   
         ░▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░ ░ 
         ▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓  ░ 
         ▒▒▒▒▒▓▒▒▓▓▓  ░ 
         ▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▓▒  ░ 
         ░▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓░░░░ 
          ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒  
           ▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒░  
           ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░   
            ░▒▒▒▒▒▒░    
               ░░       

        Icon (32 x 32):

                      ░░░░              
                  ░░░░░░░░░░░░          
                ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░          
               ░░▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░  ░      
            ░ ░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒  ░     
           ░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░  ░    
           ▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒    ░   
           ▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░       
           ░░░░░░░░▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒       
          ░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░      
          ░░░░░░░░░░░ ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒      
         ░▒▒░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒      
         ░▒▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▒░    ░ 
         ░▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒     ▒ 
         ░▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒    ░▒ 
         ░▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒    ░░ 
         ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▒    ░  
         ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒░░░░░▓▓▓▓▒░░   ░  
          ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░ ░░░  
          ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░  
          ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░░░  
           ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░▒░  
           ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒   
            ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒░   
             ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒░    
             ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░     
              ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░      
               ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒       
                ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░        
                  ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░          


        Icon (48 x 48):


                              ░░░░                      
                         ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░                 
                       ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░               
                     ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  ░             
                   ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒░              
              ░   ░░░▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒░  ░░         
              ░░ ░░▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒░   ░        
             ░░▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒░   ░       
             ░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░ ░░  ░░      
             ▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░     ░      
             ▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░           
             ▒░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒           
             ░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░          
            ░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒░▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒          
           ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒          
           ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓░         
           ░░▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░         
          ░░▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▒ ▒     ░░  
          ░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒ ░     ░▒  
          ░▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒       ▒▒  
          ░▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░▒▒▒▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒       ▒░  
          ░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒       ▒░  
          ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒      ░░   
          ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░     ░░   
          ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░     ░░   
           ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░     ░░   
           ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░  ░░░░░   
           ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒ ░░ ░░░░░    
            ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░    
            ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░▒▒    
             ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▓░░░░░░░░░▒▒    
             ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░░░░░░▒▒░    
              ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░▒▓▒     
              ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒░     
               ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░      
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░       
                ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░        
                 ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░         
                  ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░          
                   ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▒▒░          
                    ░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░           
                     ░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░             
                        ░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░                





_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 65379096
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 42982583
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x3e59b17
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x3e00001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 9597
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "OgrePC"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                program specified minimum size: 300 by 154
                program specified maximum size: 32767 by 32767
                window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Mozilla Firefox"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Mozilla Firefox"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Mozilla Firefox"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Mozilla Firefox"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a KDE user, but after some searching, I found [this forum tread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=121941) by someone who had the same problem. Here what was the solution:

> Try to add a window rule ("kcmshell4 kwinrules") and in the
>   "appearance & FIXES" tab, set "Accept Focus" to "Force" and "Yes".

Comment: Tnx for the effort but proposed solution does not work for me... It seems that this is some nasty bug that advertises itself only when swing is used along with "Show desktop"...

Comment: @Ogre_BGR The thing to verify is if the desktop itself takes the focus.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't know how to check that. Cannot find any tool for it...

Comment: @Ogre_BGR Could you add the output of xprop to your question???

Comment: Done. Added xprop for the 3 components involved.

Comment: @Ogre_BGR The top part of the xprop is missing in the 3 dumps, could you paste them to simething like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23429/discussion-between-retrodroid-and-ogre-bgr).

Comment: Done. Added it here with icon "images" removed

Comment: I see, your problem is not from the same source

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Intelij products, but I use Gnome 3. For example, if I launch RubyMine and switch to terminal and continue to work with it, Rubymine steals focus at lest two times while its starts. It also steals focus when some event happens; this usually ends up with a piece of shell command in the source code opened for editing in Rubymine. I already had erotic experience of looking for syntax errors in a code that's work perfect couple of moments ago. Thanks to unknown hero who gave it to me with a best intentions.

I think this is X-server bug, as not only KDE affected.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.